# Create Time object with miliseconds in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, iso8601

I want to have a Time object that can be converted into the iso8601 format:
"2022-10-01T22:38:45.100Z"

I tried this:

```
Time.utc(2022, 10, 1, 22, 38, 45, 100).in_time_zone.iso8601(3)
```

but this gives me "2022-10-01T22:38:45.000Z" instead of "2022-10-01T22:38:45.100Z"
the miliseconds info somehow is gone. its always 000

what am i doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're 3 zeros off:

```rb
>> Time.utc(2022, 10, 1, 22, 38, 45, 100)
=> 2022-10-01 22:38:45.0001 UTC
#                         ^
# NOTE: These are microseconds.
#       aka `usec`
>> Time.utc(2022, 10, 1, 22, 38, 45, 100).usec
=> 100
```

Times a 1000 to get into milisecond range:

```
>> Time.utc(2022, 10, 1, 22, 38, 45, 123_000).in_time_zone.iso8601(3)
=> "2022-10-01T22:38:45.123Z"
```

---

*https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/time#method-c-utc*